# Java regex take numbers from String

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to take number's from string

example:

```
1223_:2 
234423_:5
```

I only want to take this number's to `_:`

any idea for

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile(??????????)
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether I got you right: do you want only the first part of the number (e.g. 1223) or the whole number without "_:" (e.g. 12232)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What’s with the regex requirement?

```
String number = someOtherString.substring(0, someOtherString.indexOf('_:'));
```

Comment: this bring me the number after the "_:"
I just want the numbers before this "_:"

got resolution - take the index of "_:" and also use substring but with range substring(int, int)

anyway thanks for take the good way :)

Comment: Yes, forgot the `0,` part. Fixed. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
yourString.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "1223_:2 234423_:5";
String[] numbers = str.trim().split("_:\\d+\\s*");
```

For a better answer we are gonna need more details. What exactly do you want to do?